# Postgres greater than or null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to efficiently use an index for the greater than or null query.

Example of a query would be:

`select * from table where date > '2020-01-01' or date is null`

What index if any do I need that postgres will be able to do this efficiently. I tried doing an index with

`create index date on table (date asc nulls last)`

but it does not seem to work and the best I am able to get is two bitmaps scans (one for greater than and one for null).

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for this query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are able to rewrite your condition, you could replace the `null` value with a date that is guaranteed to be greater than the comparison value:

```
where coalesce(date, 'infinity') > date '2020-01-01'
```

Then create an index on that expression:

```
create index on the_table ( (coalesce(date, 'infinity')) )
```

See also PostgreSQL docs:

- Date/Time Types, [8.5.1.4. Special Values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-VALUES) for `infinity` value
- Conditional Expressions, [9.18.2. COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) for `coalesce` function

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for. This way I only need to change filtering code and not all the places data is returned to.

Comment: @BlažŠnuderl: depending no how that date is used in other places you might want to consider storing `infinity` directly in the table instead of null

Answer (score 2):

Does Postgres use the index correctly when you use `union all`?

```
select *
from table
where date > '2020-01-01' 
union all
select *
from table
where date is null;
```

The issue might be the inequality combined with the `NULL` comparison.  If this is some sort of "end date", then you might consider using some far out future value such as 9999-01-01 or `infinity`.

Comment: Its exactly a far out date :) 

If nothing better comes up I am considering using a far out date as suggested but that will require changing quite a bit of business logic to account for that.

Comment: 'infinity' is also a valid date in the far future: SELECT 'today' < 'infinity'::date;

Comment: Don't use year 9999 in PostgreSQL. There is `DATE 'infinity'` which expresses the intention more clearly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Does `infinity` use indexes correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is a normal value like all others.